# Kendo grid is showing json data instead of the actual grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to launch a Kendo grid in a Kendo popup Window but instead of the grid showing, I'm getting the json data.

[image]

This is the code from my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int id)
    {
        var model = Service.FindOne("Cashflows", x => x.Id == id);
        var cashflows = new List<flows>();

        foreach (var cf in model.CashFlows)
        {
            var flow = new flows
            {
                Id = cf.Id,
                AssetId = cf.Id,
                MortgageValue = cf.MortgageValue,
                Year = cf.Year
            };
            cashflows.Add(flow);
        }

        var result = cashflows.ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is what I have in my Kendo View.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModels.Finance.flows>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
    columns.Bound(p => p.AssetId);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Year);
    columns.Bound(p => p.MortgageValue);
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Finance"))
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .PageSize(5)
)
.Pageable()
)
```

Comment: Check if all the required JS files are included. The fact that you are using AllowGet when returning JSON shows that those files are probably not included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the return command to:

```
return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```