# MVC Telerik grid not binding only displaying json data in browser

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am trying to get a telerik grid to display json data that is being return from a controller action but the only it displays the actual json data in the browser window.

1. Am i supposed to call .BindTo after read?
2. Am i doing something wrong in my action?
3. am i going about this all wrong?

   ```
       [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult ReadLeads([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
   {


       var model = new RecordLookupViewModel();

       using (var db = new RGI_MasterEntities())
       {

           db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

           var results = db.tblMasterLeads
               .Where(
                   x => (model.FirstName == null || x.FirstName.Equals("Eric"))
                        && (model.RecordType == null || x.MasterLeadType.Equals("Responder"))
               )
               .Select(s => new LookupGridResults
               {
                   FirstName = s.FirstName,
                   LastName = s.LastName,
                   City = s.city,
                   State = s.state,
                   County = s.county,
                   Zip = s.zip
               }).Take(10);

           var result = results.ToDataSourceResult(request);

           return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }
   }
   ```

Hers is my view code for the grid.

```
                                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<LookupGridResults>()
.Name("grid")
.AutoBind(false)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains"))).Width(225);
    columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Width(225).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
    columns.Bound(p => p.City).Width(225).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
    columns.Bound(p => p.County).Width(225).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
    columns.Bound(p => p.State).Width(225).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
    columns.Bound(p => p.Zip).Width(225).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadLeads", "LeadsManagement").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))

 )

                                )
```

Here are my results btw.

```
{"Data":[{"LastName":"COFFEY","FirstName":"EDWARD","City":"FRANKFORT","County":"FRANKLIN","State":"KY","Zip":"40601-2304"},{"LastName":"DESPAIN","FirstName":"TONY","City":"CAMPBELLSVILLE","County":"TAYLOR","State":"KY","Zip":"42718-9397"},{"LastName":"HALBIG","FirstName":"RONALD","City":"CAMPBELLSVILLE","County":"TAYLOR","State":"KY","Zip":"42718-1556"},{"LastName":"KRAUS","FirstName":"REBECCA","City":"FRANKFORT","County":"FRANKLIN","State":"KY","Zip":"40601-2714"},{"LastName":"LAWLESS","FirstName":"MEREDITH","City":"CAMPBELLSVILLE","County":"TAYLOR","State":"KY","Zip":"42718-1556"},{"LastName":"RANKIN","FirstName":"PAULINE","City":"LAWRENCEBURG","County":"ANDERSON","State":"KY","Zip":"40342-1374"},{"LastName":"SHIRLEY","FirstName":"LORRAINE","City":"CAMPBELLSVLLE","County":"TAYLOR","State":"KY","Zip":"42718-1557"},{"LastName":"STAPLES","FirstName":"DAMON","City":"HODGENVILLE","County":"LARUE","State":"KY","Zip":"42748-1208"},{"LastName":"WILLIAMS","FirstName":"LUCY","City":"FRANKFORT","County":"FRANKLIN","State":"KY","Zip":"40601-2308"},{"LastName":"WILSON","FirstName":"BELIDA","City":"FRANKFORT","County":"FRANKLIN","State":"KY","Zip":"40601-1321"}],"Total":10,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

Comment: the 2 parts of code you're showing looks fine.. not sure you need `.AutoBind(false)` sounds like you might be missing a javascript library reference

Comment: That didnt do it. I feel like im missing something. Not sure what yet.

Comment: Do you have this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143886/kendo-ui-grid-shows-json-instead-of-grid-asp-net-razor

Comment: This one also looks familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530969/kendo-grid-is-showing-json-data-instead-of-the-actual-grid

Comment: This one speaks to the point that @JamieD77 referenced: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829235/kendo-ui-grid-returns-json-to-browser-using-mvc

Comment: Mark, those two look great but i tried the first one and it didnt change anything and the answer to the second one, im already doing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, it seemed i was missing a reference to a bundle.  I do credit  Mark Schultheiss for pointing me in the right direction.

Got it completly working today. Here is what fixed it.

1. I changed my actionresult to a JsonResult.
2. I had filtering turned on in the grid but none of my columns had filtering attributes.

I think thats about it. It works great now.